# BigQuery error in load operation: URI not found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, parquet

I have, in the same GCP project, a BigQuery dataset and a cloud storage bucket, both within the region us-central1. The storage bucket has a single parquet file located in it. When I run the below command:

```
bq load \
--project_id=myProject --location=us-central1 \
--source_format=PARQUET \
myDataSet:tableName \
gs://my-storage-bucket/my_parquet.parquet
```

It fails with the below error:

```
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job '[job_no]': Not found: URI gs://my-storage-bucket/my_parquet.parquet
```

Removing the `--project_id` or `--location` tags don't affect the outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out - the documentation is incorrect, I actually had to declare the source as `gs://my-storage-bucket/my_parquet.parquet/part*` and it loaded fine

Comment: I was surprised that the full path didn't work. I had read that we can use wildcards, but it was not obvious to use them for paruqet from the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

There has been some internal issues with BigQuery on 3rd March and it has been fixed now.

I have confirmed and used the following command to upload successfully a parquet file from Cloud Storage to BigQuery Table using bq command:

```
bq load --project_id=PROJECT_ID \
--source_format=PARQUET \
DATASET.TABLE_NAME gs://BUCKET/FILE.parquet
```

Please note that according to the [**BigQuery Official Documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet#loading_parquet_data_into_a_new_table), you have to declare the name of the table as following `DATASET.TABLE_NAME` ( In the post, I can see : instead of . )